# how to create a line between two clicks using menu in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to create a paint application where in i am using a menu to show the shapes i can draw and i have added some shapes such as line,rectangle,circle but i am unable to use the OnLButtonDown function within the line function so i would like to know how can i create a line between two clicks by not using LButtonDown function and any other way by which i can create a line when user clicks on the menu my sample code is pasted below:

```
#include<afxwin.h>
#include"resource.h"
class myframe:public CFrameWnd
{
        public:
    myframe()
    {
        Create(0,"simple",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,rectDefault,0,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));
    }
    void shape(int id)
    {
        CClientDC d(this);
        CPen p;
        p.CreatePen(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(255,0,0));
        d.SelectObject(&p);
        switch(id)
        {
        case 101:


            d.MoveTo(100,100);
            d.LineTo(200,200);
            break;
        case 102:
            d.Rectangle(10,10,100,200);
            break;
        case 103:
            d.Ellipse(20,20,100,100);
            break;
    }
    }
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(myframe,CFrameWnd)
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(101,103,shape)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
class myapp:public CWinApp
{
public:
    int InitInstance()

    {
        myframe *f;
        f=new myframe();
        f->ShowWindow(3);
        m_pMainWnd=f;
        return 1;
    }
};
myapp a;
```

Comment: What problem are you facing in using `OnLButtonDown`? Also please use named constants instead of numbers such as 101, 102, 103.

Comment: i want to create a random line which user is able to draw between two clicks and i am unable to do that can you help me use constants instead of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago, Microsoft published a sample application written in MFC that does exactly this.

It's called **Scribble**, and you can download it and following along with the written tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716527.aspx).

Once you've done that, you can learn how to upgrade an existing MFC application to use the new Ribbon user interface. That tutorial is available here: [Updating the MFC Scribble Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983935.aspx)

Comment: is there any other solution whereby any changes to my program would help me

Comment: @jhonny: I don't really know what you're asking. It's obvious from the code that you've shown that you don't really understand the message-driven model used in Windows programming. You need a solid introduction to writing an MFC application, not a change in one or two lines of your code. A sample application is the best way I know to do that. You *should* be using `OnLButtonDown`. If you can't figure out how to do that, something is wrong.